# Is my MacBook security compromised?

Tags: mac, macos, safari, security

About a week ago, I installed an application in my MacBook from a dubious source. Since then I noticed some weird behaviours.

First, while I was making a bank transfer in Safari, I got the following popup warning:

> “Safari” would like to control this computer using accessibility
>   features

I denied the access, as it never asked for it before and I saw no reason to grant it.

A couple of days later, while I was browsing, I clicked on a google result and got redirected to a blank page. I thought the site was not working so I clicked back. I then got this message:

[image]

Which was not the site I clicked at all in Google results. I got back to Google results and clicked again on the same result. I was redirected to the correct page without any problem.

I got suspicious and installed Antivirus Thor Lite from the App Store. It detected several infected files with Pua.Win.Trojan. But I think that these are files infected with Windows viruses and that they don't compromise my Mac. Malwarebytes does not detect any issue either.

Right now I'm suspecting that I may be somehow infected. What do you guys think? Whats the best way to know for sure if I'm infected?

Comment: Did you check which extensions are active on your browser? It is possible that you installed by mistake a malicious extension

Answer (score 1):

download, install and run a scan from Malwarebytes for Mac. Sounds like you have malware installed.

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the original post, but I also ran Malwarebytes and it finds no issues.